# When was it first revealed how Anakin became Darth Vader?

Tags: star-wars

I remember knowing back in the mid-80s that Luke's father and Obi-Wan Kenobi fought on a lava planet which resulted in Luke's father being hurt badly enough to need the head-to-toe black leather outfit with cape and flashing lights that we knew already as Darth Vader.

But at that time, where would I have learned this from? Was it mentioned in one of the novel adaptations of movies IV, V or VI? Or am I just psychic?

It's been bugging me for 30 years now wondering how I knew this happened.

Comment: It was mentioned in the novelizations of the original trilogy. I remember reading it as well. Someone else will probably get the right quote before me, I'm not too sure where I put my books...

Comment: I first read it in The Essential Guide to Characters which was published in 1995, though I doubt that's the original source. https://www.amazon.com/dp/0345395352/ref=cm_sw_r_cp_apa_1KbTBbM8S0FH3

Comment: https://www.quora.com/When-was-it-revealed-that-Darth-Vaders-name-was-Anakin-Skywalker

Comment: that is the same question with a sourced answer.

Comment: How is that the same question?  He isn't asking about the name.